# React Native change from circle to star symbol when TextInput secureTextEntry is set to true

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

Currently when I set the **secureTextEntry** to **true**, all the password symbols become circles: [image]

What I want to achieve is to show **stars** instead of **circles**. Here is an example:
[image]

*notice the **stars** in the second image

Thank you mates in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We cannot override that dot we see in the `TextInput` field. But we can try a workaround.

You can handle the input value using the `onKeyPress` prop that `TextInput` provides.

Below is the `onKeyPress` function that you can use. Note: `setPassword` is a  state updating function.

```js
const onKeyPress = (data: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputKeyPressEventData>) => {
  if (data.nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
    setPassword(password.slice(0, -1));
    return;
  }

  if (data.nativeEvent.key === 'Enter') {
    // On Enter handle here
    return;
  }

  if (data.nativeEvent.key === ' ') {
    setPassword(password + ' ');
    return;
  }

  if (data.nativeEvent.key === 'Tab') {
    // On Tab handle here
    return;
  }

  setPassword(password + data.nativeEvent.key);
};
```

And in the `TextInput` component, you can use it like this

```js
<TextInput
  style={styles.textInput}
  placeholder="Password"
  value={'*'.repeat(password.length)} // This is important.
  onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
/>
```

Here is an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/masked-text-input) that you can refer to. It has a working implementation. It has been tested for `Android` and `iOS` only.